# Nginx redirect requests to non existent sub directories and files to the root dir

Tags: nginx

I want to redirect all requests for non-existent subdirectories and non-existent files and files within non-existent subdirectories back to the root page.

```
Ex. sampledomain.com/jahsdjksf/sfhsafh.php
or sampledomain.com/jahsdjksf/sdfsndf/sfhsafh.php 
or sampledomain.com/sfhsafh.php
```

all back to sampledomain.com

currently I have the following added to my rules

```
root   /home/nginx/domains/randwebsite.com/public/;
index  index.php;
```

and

```
try_files    $uri $uri/ /index.php;
```

but the issue is when I try any random non-existent sub dirs it loads the main page under that url and its broken as the css etc is using that url with the non-existent sub dir however only works perfectly with non-existent files with no sub dir added

```
ex. sampledomain.com/sdlfsdlfsf.php
```

Comment: Suggest you use a web browser developer tools to try to work out what URLs it's requesting, and relate that to the access logs. That should give you a better idea what's going on and why. Edit your question with what you discover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to force a redirect, you could use a named location. Something along these lines might work for you:

```
root /home/nginx/domains/randwebsite.com/public;
index index.php;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @redirect;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri @redirect;
    ...
}
location @redirect {
    return 301 /index.php;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.